# Deleting .inf and .pnf Files

Tags: device-driver, wdk, inf

I manually install my driver using an .inf file.  Until now, I deleted the oem.inf and .pnf files from the inf folder to uninstall.  Whenever I install a new driver I delete/uninstall the old inf and pnf files.

In my old uninstalls (by deleting .inf and .pnf files), I didn't modify or delete any registry settings.

In this case do I want to change or remove any settings from the registry (for example: devnode)?

Comment: Why is this tagged "embedded"? Inappropriate use of embedded tag: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded/info

Comment: @Clifford: I added this embedded tag in an intension that people could have involved or came across this kinda situations. Am sorry if am wrong. And thanks to Clifford for fixing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the [SetupUninstallOEMInf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa377446%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to uninstall the .INF (and subsequently .PNF) files. This will take care of the details. `pnputil` (on Vista and higher) should do the equivalent thing from the command line. However, this function will not delete drivers that are currently installed (e.g. associated with a devnode).

1. Why are you uninstalling the old driver first? The user might already installed your driver for at least one devnode. Why not use a Microsoft-sanctioned solution such as `DpInst`? It will do the work required to **update** the driver.
2. Passing `SUOI_FORCEDELETE` to `SetupUninstallOEMInf` wouldn't be a good idea, cause you'd end up with lingering .INF references in your devnodes (in the registry).
3. At work I wrote a utility I called DriverUninstaller that deletes the devnodes and then deleted the INFs. **I only use this utility for uninstallations. Upgrades are handled by DpInst, as they should be.** The flow is roughly:

   1. Enumerate them with SetupAPI (e.g. by device class if your device class is unique)
   2. For each devnode, call `SetupDiCallClassInstaller(DIF_REMOVE, ...)`
   3. Call `SetupDiBuildDriverInfoList` to find all .INF files for my device
   4. For each INF, call `SetupUninstallOEMInf`

If there'll be interest in this utility, I might be able to persuade my employer to open-source it :-)

Comment: Sorry for troubling you more, as i am very fresh to the Windows Pgmming.<However, this function will not delete drivers that are currently installed (e.g. associated with a devnode)> Sry 4 poor knowledge.I am not clear with this stmt. <1.Why are you uninstalling the old driver first?----->Ans:Consider, drivers N(old-non pnp) and (N+1-new-using DPinst) are installed.The utility(not a co-installer) that i wrote will support only N+1. Now, when the user uninstalls N+1, the driver N will be rolled back. I have to avoid this situation to support my utility,which doesn't support N. Pl advice.

Comment: If there'll be interest in this utility, I might be able to persuade my employer to open-source it :-) If you are really not kidding me, it would help many other poor guys like me, indeed..

Comment: Oh, so you're uninstalling one driver and installing another one - not a new version, but a completely different driver. In this case, yes, you want to uninstall the old one. If the old driver is not a PnP driver, it is not associated with any devices in the registry (which is how PnP drivers work) so uninstalling the INF might be enough. Check the return value of SetupUninstallOEMInf to see if it succeeded.

Comment: About "this function will not delete drivers that are currently installed (e.g. associated with a devnode)": this is relevant to PnP drivers. When you install a PnP device driver, you a) copy it to the system (to Windows\Inf, DrvStore etc.), and b) install it as a device driver (as you can see in the Device Manager)

Comment: This the flow of my code to delete the inf file.. 1) SetupDiGetClassDevs --> got device information set for CLASS GUID sent 2) SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo --> Enumerated the device 3)SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty --> got the hardware 4) used strnicmp compare with my hardware ID. 5) SetupDiBuildDriverInfoList 6) SetupDiEnumDriverInfo 7) SetupDiGetDriverInfoDetail --> got the path of my inf file. 8) using DeleteFile I deleted my inf and corresponding pnf file. Is this the correct way? Please advice..

Comment: For the last part, use SetupUninstallOEMInf instead of DeleteFile because 1) it will find the PNF for you, 2) it will refuse working if there's something wrong (i.e. if someone is still using the driver), 3) it's the right way :-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15127/discussion-between-ilya-and-user1317084)

Comment: bit of a thread necro here...but I would be interested in seeing exactly what is required for a graceful cleanup or upgrade of old drivers. We currently use a legacy NSIS script and driver related operations are quite painful. 

Is your utility C++ or does DPinst use something else?

Comment: To clean old cruft (e.g. uninstall or during an install of something radically different), I have a custom C++ app using the SetupAPI functions as I wrote in my answer. For installation, DpInst is perfectly adequate.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer points out the API to remove drivers on Windows is the [SetupUninstallOEMInf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa377446%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method but I figured I'd add a few important notes here:

- the INF path parameter must be the file name only (must not include the full path!)
- this API requires Administrator privileges (this is not much of a surprise)
- on 64-bit systems, the method only works when executed in the context of a 64-bit process (ie. WOW64 doesn't work)

The [SetupDiGetDriverInfoDetail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551973(v=vs.85).aspx) API can be used to query information about the relevant INF file(s) to remove for a particular device. And the SetupDiEnumDriverInfo/SetupDiBuildDriverInfoList APIs can be used to enumerate all drivers for a particular device.

```
  // given infFilePath - full path to inf as returned by a query using SetupDiGetDriverInfoDetail
  TCHAR* infFileName = GetFileNamePart(infFilePath);
  if(SetupUninstallOEMInf(pInf, SUOI_FORCEDELETE, NULL))
  {
       // success
  }else
  {
DWORD errCode = GetLastError();
if(errCode == 0x02)
{
            //  means that the driver INF file was not found
            //  most likely it was already uninstalled 
}else if(errCode == 0x05)
      {
            //  must run as administrator
      }else
{
           // some other error code.. handle appropriately
}
  }
```

I've open-sourced the code for a tool I wrote to perform driver uninstalls for USB and Media/Image devices. Details here: http://mdinescu.com/software-development/30-driver-hunter-programatically-uninstall-drivers-in-windows

Comment: Can you please check if the code you have posted on GitHub up to date for the Driver Hunter tool ?

Comment: @Mahesh - not sure what you mean but the code was up to date when posted. I haven't made any changes that haven't been published since the last commit. Did you find anything wrong?

Comment: Sorry Mike. I was looking at the .cpp files and didn't find any Setup API calls. Looks like all the implementation went in UIDialog.h file. Thanks.